# How can I remove spaces from a string? only using indexOf() and substring()

Tags: java

This is what Ive written so far.  It checks to see whether a space exists.  If it does, it should remove it and assign the removed space string to noSpace.  But I have no idea how to remove spaces using only indexOf and substring.  Can someone please help?

```
public static String removeSpace(String s)
  {
  String noSpace = "";

  if(s.indexOf(" ") == -1)
  {   
     noSpace = s;
  }

  else
  {
     for(int a = 1; a <= s.length(); a++)
     { 
        if()
           noSpace = s.substring(0,a);   
     }

  }      


  return noSpace;         
}
```

Comment: You can't, with just those two functions.  You also need, at a minimum, `concat`.

Comment: He can, but it would be good to utilize other functions. @HotLicks

Comment: @HotLicks see my answer, I think you may be wrong about that...

Comment: @HotLicks it's definitely possible. Not recommendable  by any means, but possible.

Comment: my teacher does allow me to use other functions.  Because we have to follow the collegeboard's guidelines sicne this is AP Com Sci

Comment: @PTheCoolGuy of course - that's the way it'll be for your first year. It's good to learn that way, figuring out how stuff works instead of calling some method to do it for you.

Comment: @AlexK - No, you used `concat`.  Or else used StringBuilder -- I'm not sure which the compiler generates under the covers for `+`.

Comment: @HotLicks all right. Technically, you're right. But he's not explicitly using it. Whatever happens under the hood stays under the hood. There are a trillion functions called under the hood. Then he can't do anything.

Comment: @AlexK - Actually, there aren't that many calls done "under the hood" like that.  String concatenation and `toString` are probably the biggies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string.indexOf(" ")` will return -1 if a space doesn't exist. Otherwise, it returns the index of the first instance of a space. So all you have to do is check if it returns something other than -1:

```
int index = s.indexOf(" ");
if(index != -1) {
}
```

Then cut the space out by taking the substring up to the space, and then from the index after the space:

```
noSpace = s.substring(0,index) + s.substring(index + 1);
```

That's it!

You get something like this:

```
String s = "space testing";
while(s.indexOf(" ") != -1) {
    s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(" ")) + s.substring(s.indexOf(" ") + 1);
}
```

Comment: `trim()` will save unnecessary iterations, but leading or trailing spaces aren't a problem in this case

Comment: @outlyer you're right actually, in this case. We don't need that :) good call!

Comment: so i tested the code, but since s does contain spaces, wouldnt the while loop be infinite.  Thats what my compiler says

Comment: @PTheCoolGuy No, `s` changes with each iteration of the loop, removing an space, until a point where it will have no spaces and hence the loop condition won't be met anymore

Comment: @PTheCoolGuy I just ran this code myself and it works perfectly. It'll remove the spaces until the condition is not met anymore.

Comment: YES, im sorry. i had set `noSpace` equal to the code

Answer (score 2):

You just need to call `indexOf()` repeatedly until no more spaces are found, rebuilding the string with `substring()` after each space is (by joining the parts before and after the space).

```
String noSpace = s;
int idx;
while (-1 != (idx = noSpace.indexOf(" "))) {
    noSpace = noSpace.substring(0,idx) + noSpace.substring(idx+1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String testString = " ";
    System.out.println("Before remmoveSpace:" + testString);
    System.out.println("After remmoveSpace:" + removeSpace(testString));

    testString = " StartWithEmpty";
    System.out.println("Before remmoveSpace:" + testString);
    System.out.println("After remmoveSpace:" + removeSpace(testString));

    testString = "There are a few spaces separated by letters ";
    System.out.println("Before remmoveSpace:" + testString);
    System.out.println("After remmoveSpace:" + removeSpace(testString));

    testString = "There  Are2SpacesConsessConsecutively";
    System.out.println("Before remmoveSpace:" + testString);
    System.out.println("After remmoveSpace:" + removeSpace(testString));

  }

  public static String removeSpace(String s) {

    int firstIndexOfSpace = s.indexOf(" ");
    if (firstIndexOfSpace == -1) {
      return s;
    } else {
      return s.substring(0, firstIndexOfSpace)
          + removeSpace(s.substring(firstIndexOfSpace + 1, s.length()));
    }

  }
```

> Result:
>  Before remmoveSpace: 
>  After remmoveSpace:
>   Before remmoveSpace: StartWithEmpty
>  After
>   remmoveSpace:StartWithEmpty
>  Before remmoveSpace:There are a few
>   spaces separated by letters 
>  After
>   remmoveSpace:Thereareafewspacesseparatedbyletters
>  Before
>   remmoveSpace:There  Are2SpacesConsessConsecutively
>  After
>   remmoveSpace:ThereAre2SpacesConsessConsecutively

Answer (score 1):

You cut and append string removing white space

```
String str = "abc asd";
while(true){
int whiteSpaceIndex =  str.indexOf(" ");
if(whiteSpaceIndex != -1) {

  // if the space was the last character of String ? 
  // Yes --> then don't care for part after first clip
  // No --> then append the part after the space character

  int nextStartIndex = str.length() - whiteSpaceIndex > 1 ? whiteSpaceIndex + 1 : whiteSpaceIndex;
  if(nextStartIndex != whiteSpaceIndex) {
     str = str.substring(0, whiteSpaceIndex) + str.substring(nextStartIndex);
  }else {
     str = str.substring(0, whiteSpaceIndex)
  }
}
}
```